# Update a content type field via db not working D8

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type field with **machine name** **`field_p_frontip`** and for that i have a table **`node__field_p_frontip`** and in that there is field value like **`field_p_frontip_value`** . Eventhough i manually inserted a value in to that field its not taking effect in the front end . I updated the value in the **`node_revision__field_p_frontip`** table too and cleared the **cache** .Why its not working ,any idea ?

I done this because i done via `hook_form_alter` and its not taking effect .

`node__field_p_frontip` table structre :

```
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle                | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted               | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| langcode              | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_p_frontip_value | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and `node_revision__field_p_frontip` table structure :

```
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bundle                | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| deleted               | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| entity_id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| revision_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| langcode              | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| delta                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| field_p_frontip_value | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**From Berdir's comment**

---

I was trying to set the value of the field '`field_p_frontip`' in form_alter as follows , but both didnt worked .

`$form['field_p_frontip']["en"][0]['#default_value']['value'] ='192.168.1.100'; $form['field_p_frontip']['#default_value'] = '192.168.1.100';`

Comment: Never write into field tables directly. You're asking the wrong question, you should explain what you try to do in your form alter and what code you tried that isn't working. There is definitely a better way.

Comment: I am trying to add/modify a field's value in hook_form_alter . Itried like **$form['field_p_frontip']["en"][0]['#default_value']['value'] ='192.168.1.100';
    $form['field_p_frontip']['#default_value'] = '192.168.1.100'** , both didnt worked ,that y i tried modifying db

Comment: If you want to set the default value of the field, why not simply configure the field. It sounds like you overall are doing something very wrong. If you wrote in your question what you want to achieve, what you have done and where you are stuck, we can help you a lot better. Right now you have only said where you are stuck, but it sounds so wrong that we can't help. Also the code you provided in your update is wrong for Drupal 8.

Comment: @googletorp , what i want to do is set the value of a field on hook_form_alter and update the field programmatically , not from front end

Comment: So what you want to do, is to update the value of a field of one or more existing nodes?

Comment: @googletorp for a single node at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the value of a field for a node, you need to.

1. Load it
2. Modify it
3. Save it

In code it looks like this:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
if ($node) {
  $node->field_p_frontip = '192.168.1.100';
  $node->save();
}
```

How you set the value of the field, depends on the field itself. Most fields are simple, and can be set with a scalar value. If field has multiple values or stores more complex data (like the address field), you need to account for this complexity. Usually this is done with arrays.